# Is it true that for all sets $A, B$, $|A \cap B| \geqslant \frac{1}{2}|A||B|$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Or is this only true for downsets?  Thanks!

Comment: could you restate the question in the text, I'm not sure I understand

Comment: What's "downsets"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, for example if $A$ and $B$ have an empty intersection.